# Woocommerce Porto Theme Hide Selected Categroy for Breadcrumbs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

I try everything. My breadcrumbs is not default to Woocommerce.

I use Porto Theme for Wordpress.
This is my breadrumbs.php

```
<?php
global $porto_settings;

$breadcrumbs = $porto_settings['show-breadcrumbs'] ? porto_get_meta_value( 'breadcrumbs', true ) : false;
$page_title  = $porto_settings['show-pagetitle'] ? porto_get_meta_value( 'page_title', true ) : false;

if ( ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) || is_front_page() ) {
    $breadcrumbs = false;
    $page_title  = false;
}

$title      = isset( $porto_shortcode_title ) ? $porto_shortcode_title : porto_page_title();
$sub_title  = isset( $porto_shortcode_sub_title ) ? $porto_shortcode_sub_title : porto_page_sub_title();
$hide_title = ! $title || ! $page_title;

if ( isset( $is_shortcode ) ) {
    $hide_title  = false;
    $breadcrumbs = isset( $hide_breadcrumb ) ? false : true;
}
?>
<div class="container<?php echo ! $hide_title ? '' : ' hide-title'; ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="<?php echo ! $hide_title ? '' : ' d-none'; ?>">
                <h1 class="page-title<?php echo ! $sub_title ? '' : ' b-none'; ?>"><?php echo porto_strip_script_tags( $title ); ?></h1>
                <?php
                if ( $sub_title ) :
                    ?>
                    <p class="page-sub-title"><?php echo porto_strip_script_tags( $sub_title ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ( $breadcrumbs ) : ?>
                <div class="breadcrumbs-wrap<?php echo ! $sub_title ? '' : ' breadcrumbs-with-subtitle'; ?>">
                    <?php echo porto_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php

            porto_breadcrumbs_filter();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe someone knows how to set remove chosen category by id or slug remove for breadcrumbs with PHP Code functions.php?

Best regards